# Parsing Page div into array JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a div in an online page that contains perfectly parsed data. For example a div named "info" that would contain:

```
region,sales,cost
America,12,5
Europe,32,6
```

What is the most optimal(performance wise) way in JavaScript/Jquery to:

1. read the div in the page (scrape contents)
2. parse the div by ','
3. store it into a 2d Array

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: By "read page", do you mean scraping the content from a different page/server. If so, clientside javascript is not the right tool for the job.

Comment: can scrape a page using Yahoo YQL and make a call to YQL with `$.getJSON` (or `$.ajax` or `$.get`) and return the content of your DIV within a JSON result. Otherwise set up a scraper on your server to parse external page

Comment: Yes adeneo. I need to scrape the content from a different page. What is the right tool?

Comment: [whathaveyoutried.com](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: Are you scraping it on the client or the server?

Comment: Just on a simple client website. The source is also public on a website

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//get string using ajax, JSONP, or whatever means you have
var str = "region,sales,cost\nAmerica,12,5\nEurope,32,6";

var lines = str.split("\n");
//first line is names of keys
var names = lines.shift().split(',');

var countries = [];

lines.forEach(function (line) {
    var obj = {};
    line.split(',').forEach(function (piece, idx) {
        //we know data is well-formed.  Name for each piece will exist
        obj[names[idx]] = piece;
    });
    countries.push(obj);
});
```

Comment: Thanks what jquery calls should I look into to get the actual string?

Comment: @fredykruger are you getting it from your own domain or from another domain?

Comment: I am scraping from my own domain.

Comment: In that case just use `$.get('/path/to/page/that/prints/data', function (data) {`

Comment: Fantastic and to do cross domain scraping, any suggestions to look into?

Comment: @fredykruger you need some help from the other domain: it has to support your request.  Google JSONP

Answer (score 1):

How I would do it is:

```
var data = []
   , text = /*select inner HTML of div*/

text.split('\n')
    .forEach(function (line) { 
      data.push(line.split(','))
    })
```

I'm doing this from an iPhone so forgive me if there are a few typos. 
If your data is not fully broken into line breaks, I would just split all your data by commas, and loop trough it while maintaining an inner counter that ticks off every 3 items, which will indicate that you have parsed a new data array.

Comment: This is great, how do you select the inner HTML of another website though. Jquery functions?

Comment: That's a bit tougher, I'm not 100 percent sure. I would focus on scraping a site using jquery's Ajax library. I would take that resulting data and instantiate some elements in the DOM. You could also do a bit of crude Regex parsing if the resulting HTML data is pretty predictable. (I would stay away from the latter though)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
var divContent = $('div').html(); // replace 'div' for correct selector
var result = new Array();

var splitContent = divContent.split('\n'); // Split the content with new line caracter
// Get the index for initial lines
var indexes = splitContent[0].split(',');
// the initial value 1 is for ignore first line
for (var i = 1; i < splitContent.length; i++) { 
    result[i-1] = new Array();
    var items = splitContent[i].split(',');
    for (var j = 0; j < items.length; j++)  {
        result[i-1][indexes[j]] = items[j];
    }
}
```

I tested and this works.

Ps: Please, make sure than after  tag has no other break line or this code don't work.